# Matplotlib.pyplot.scatter x and y value must be the same size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I feel like I am going crazy. What I want to do is create a scatter plot with an x axis split into 10 segments, with multiple values in each segment in the Y axis. For example:

```
PP = [pp1m, pp2m, pp3m, pp4m, pp5m, pp6m, pp7m, pp8m, pp9m, pp10m]
timeline = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
plt.scatter(timeline, PP)
```

In the above, PP consists of 10 lists containing 33 values each. Am I using the wrong graph type or just organizing my data incorrectly?

Comment: `PP` should be a `list` of numbers not a `list of list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the PP list like this:

```
for sublist in PP:
    plt.scatter(timeline, sublist)
```

Comment: Dang, I thought that was gonna work! Since pp1m (and all the others) contain 33 values each it is still getting the same 'x and y must be the same size' error.

Comment: I don't understand. Did my solution work or not?

Comment: Changed PP to be a list that is 33 objects long containing 10 values each instead and your answer works! Much appreciated!